# How to use SUMIFS function for summing values if criteria range exists in a range?

Tags: excel, sumifs

My data:

```
A   B    C
a   3    d
b   1    a
c   8    e
d   5
```

I want to use `SUMIFS` function, sum range is `B1:B4`, if the corresponding value in column `A` exists in column `C`, sum the values in column `B`,
in this case the sum will be `3 + 5 = 8`
I tried `=SUMIFS(B1:B4,A1:A4, COUNTIF($C$1:$C$3,A1)` but I get zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A1:A4,C1:C3,B1:B4))
```

Link for further reading: [COUNTIFS: Multiple “OR” Criteria For One Or Two Criteria_Ranges](https://web.archive.org/web/20141014072615/https://excelxor.com/2014/09/02/countifs-multiple-or-criteria-for-one-or-two-criteria_ranges/)

Comment: Thanks, can't you solve it with sumifs? I remember I saw somewhere someone used {} parantheses (not an array formula) to check if value exists in range specified by these parantheses.

Comment: You can't escape using some form of additional summing function applied to the SUMIF(S). The only difference is that, if you reference the column C values as an array constant within the formula, you can use SUM in place of SUMPRODUCT, i.e. =SUM(SUMIF(A1:A4,{"d","a","c"},B1:B4)), though obviously hard-coding these values in the formula itself loses some flexibility. Besides, SUMPRODUCT is hardly something which warrants avoidance!

Comment: Also note that neither of these two solutions is an array formula (in the sense of requiring CSE-entry, that is.)

Comment: Sir, thank you. Can't you replace  `{"d","a","c"}` with a range in `=SUM(SUMIF(A1:A4,{"d","a","c"},B1:B4))`?

Comment: You can, but the SUM then needs to become SUMPRODUCT. Forgive me, but do you have an issue with using SUMPRODUCT? As I said, such a formula does NOT require entering with CSE, if that was your worry?

Comment: Because I don't know how to use SUMPRODUCT, never used it. And I'm scared to use it :) I used SUMIFS, and I think it is a powerful function that can do every kind of conditional summings. Silly, ain't it?

Comment: Ha! Don't fear the SUMPRODUCT! Actually, in this type of construction the two form a powerful alliance. All SUMPRODUCT (or SUM) does in these cases is to coerce SUMIF to operate over more than one criteria. Effectively, =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A1:A4,C1:C3,B1:B4)) is equivalent to: =SUMIF(A1:A4,C1,B1:B4)+SUMIF(A1:A4,C2,B1:B4)+SUMIF(A1:A4,C3,B1:B4). Does that help? I've added a link to my answer for further reading on multiple "OR" criteria within SUMIF(S)/COUNTIF(S) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this:

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B4,A1:A4,A1)
```

Edit:

I know you asked for a sumif, but that doesn't want to work, entering the below as an array formula (`CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`) does the trick.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B4,(IFERROR(MATCH(A1:A4,C1:C4,0),0)>0)*1)
```

Comment: But it doesnt check column C. Column C has values d, a, e. So, I want to sum the values in column B, if corresponding letter in column A exists in column C. Therefore I sum 3 and 5

Comment: Added an alternative.