# How to use SUMIFS and SUMPRODUCT function **with a multiplier column** for summing values if criteria range exists in a range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, sumifs

This question refers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805571/how-to-use-sumifs-function-for-summing-values-if-criteria-range-exists-in-a-rang).

This is the original question:

```
A   B    C 
a   3    d 
b   1    a 
c   8    e 
d   5
```

> I want to use `SUMIFS` function, sum range is `B1:B4`, if the corresponding value in column `A` exists in column `C`, sum the values in column `B`, in this case the sum will be `3 + 5 = 8`.

The answer turned out to be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A1:A4,C1:C3,B1:B4))
```

---

I would like to create the same result, but with a multiplier on one of the ranges.

Here's my question:

```
A   B   C   D
a   3   d   3
b   1   a   1
c   8   e   1
d   5   d   3
```

The only thing I would like to do differently is add a range `D1:D3` that acts as a multiplier. In this case, the sum I want would be `(3x3)+(5x3)= 24`.

One challenge is that the ranges are different sizes in the "Test Data" google sheet linked below. The "Test Data" sheet is an example of how I would like to total daily calories based on the number of servings of items that I eat as dictated by the "multiplier column."

I would like the numbers in `C2:C27` to be a multiplier and factored into the total in `D36`.

For example, if I ate 2 servings of Beef, then 2 servings worth of Beef's ​calories would be displayed in the daily totals below the data. Currently, using the formula =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Meal_Items!$A$2:$A$100,$D$2:$D$28,Meal_Items!$B$2:$B$100)), only 1 serving of beef is weighted.

[Test Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vs380_PLwCT2wBdeyQ2regQwWWIQZKFOqk788rYr3xI/edit?usp=sharing)

See linked Test Data set above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original question could also be solved with this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(C1:C3,A1:A4)>0)+0,B1:B4)`

using that version it's a simple matter to add one or more multiplier columns

`=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(C1:C3,A1:A4)>0)+0,B1:B4,D1:D4)`

Given discussion in comments this formula should do what you want in either Excel or google sheets

`=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(LOOKUP($D$2:$D$28,Meal_Items!$A$2:$A$100‌​,Meal_Items!$B$2:$B$‌​100),0),$C$2:$C$28)`

Comment: Thanks, Barry! I just tried this in the Test Data sheet that I linked in above but returned an error because the range sizes are different. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which range sizes? In the above A1:A4, B1:B4 and D1:D4 all have to be the same size but C1:C3 (as in that formula) doesn't need to match. Which formula did you use?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you check the Test Data sheet linked in? Here's the equivalencies; A1:A4 is Meal_Items!$A$2:$A$100, B1:B4 is Meal_Items!$B$2:$B$100, D1:D4 is $C$2:$C$28, and C1:C3  is $D$2:$D$28. So A1:A4 is Meal_Items!$A$2:$A$100 is the range that doesn't match. Also, you will see that a couple ranges are on a different tab. Thoughts?

Comment: Your edited question makes it different than I imagined - you can just add the `C2:C100` range in to the existing formula like this:  `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Meal_Items!$A$2:$A$100,$D$2:$D$28,Meal_Items!$B$2:$B$100),$C$2:$C$28)`

Comment: Got it, just tried it, I am returning "#Error!" "formula parse error"

Comment: OK, that version works in Excel but apparently not in google sheets. Given that Meal_Items!$A$2:$A$100 is in ascending order you can use `LOOKUP` - this version should work in both Excel and google sheets - `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(LOOKUP($D$2:$D$28,Meal_Items!$A$2:$A$100,Meal_Items!$B$2:$B$100),0),$C$2:$C$28)`

Comment: to be clear; I tried =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(LOOKUP($D$2:$D$28,Meal_Items!$A$2:$A$100‌​,Meal_Items!$B$2:$B$‌​100),0),$C$2:$C$28 and it worked perfectly in Google Sheets, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you have actually put A, B, C, etc into the header row (row 1) then this will not work until you either rename your header column labels appropriately or use data range references in place of the full column references I've provided.

```
=B2*INDEX(B:B, MATCH(A2, A:A, 0))+B2*INDEX(B:B, MATCH(C2, A:A, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

In **E1** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C$4,A1)>0,1,0)
```

and copy down.  Then in another cell:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E1:E4)*(D1:D4)*(B1:B4))
```

[image]

Data is in column **B**
Weights are in column **D**
Criteria are in column **E**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the test data set, I tried =SUMPRODUCT((E2:E27)*(C2:C27)*(Meal_Items!B2:B7)) but the "array arguments to multiply are a different size" and I get an error. Any thoughts?

Comment: @NathanBauman  Perhaps:   =SUMPRODUCT((E2:E27)*(C2:C27)*(Meal_Items!B2:B27))